# Can't upgrade PostGIS on Ubuntu with Postgres 10?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geos

I am running Postgres 10.5 (I think) on Ubuntu 14.04. I want to upgrade to PostGIS 2.2+ so I can use `ST_Subdivide`. I've done:

```
apt install postgresql-10-postgis-2.4
```

But when I try to upgrade PostGIS from the psql interface, it won't let me:

```
 # ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
 NOTICE:  version "2.1.4" of extension "postgis" is already installed
 ALTER EXTENSION
```

What do I need to do to update?

Other useful info from the command line:

```
~# psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.5 (Ubuntu 10.5-2.pgdg14.04+1)
~# pg_config --libdir
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
# pg_config --pkglibdir
/usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib
```

And inside Postgres (NB I'm actually confused about which version of Postgres I'm running, since `SELECT version()` suggest 9.3 but the command line output above suggests 10.5):

```
# SELECT version();
                                                   version                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.3.24 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4, 64-bit
(1 row)

# SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
 POSTGIS="2.1.4 r12966" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER
```

Comment: Well, on a hunch I did `apt install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.4` and `apt install postgresql-9.3-postgis-scripts`, then `ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;`, and now I have PostGIS 2.4. But why is it that I'm using Postgres 9.3 when various things above say I'm using 10.5?

Comment: You need to run the appropriate postgis_upgrade.sql script, usually from /usr/share/postgresql/10/contrib.

Comment: It is possible to have different client and server versions installed (this is generally not a good thing). ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE runs the upgrade.sql script under the hood. This basically just inserts the functions into Postgres, that match the underlying C functions that do the actual work.

Comment: It is entirely possible that you have Postgres 9.3 and 10.x installed, but that the postmaster startup script is pointing at the 9 version, while, psql is running from 10. If you look in /usr/lib/postgresql/ you will see which version you have. You can always change the version you are running, but, you will need to be careful not to lose data, as this will be tied to a particular version. You can find out by looking at postgresql.conf.